# How to pass prop from page to layout

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-props

I currently have duplicated layout that the only difference is a prop I pass to a component:

default.vue

```html
    <template>
      <div class="page">
        <SkipToContent />
        <Header />
        <Nuxt />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </template>
```

front.vue

```html
    <template>
      <div class="page">
        <SkipToContent />
        <Header light="true" />
        <Nuxt />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </template>
```

Is there any way to pass that `light: true` from page to layout so I can use only `default.vue` layout?

I know I could emit some event on mounted but would like to prevent using lifecycle hooks for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing data up from a child is ideally done by [emitting events](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#emit), and you don't need to use lifecycle hooks for that (a custom event listener would work).

But I think a cleaner solution would be to factor out the common markup into a component that receives a `light` prop, and use them in both layouts:

```html
<!-- components/CommonLayout.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <SkipToContent />
    <Header :light="light" />
    <Nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    light: Boolean,
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- layouts/default.vue -->
<template>
  <CommonLayout />
</template>
```

```html
<!-- layouts/front.vue -->
<template>
  <CommonLayout light />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-factor-out-common-layout?file=components%2FPage.vue)